# how to combine multiple tables into 1 with mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a Mysql DB with 4 tables, with same structure and I need to merge all of this tables in a 1 table.

There are 7 fields that are the same in all tables.

Is there any way to merge the tables ?

Thank you very much

Comment: Look up `join`.

Comment: You mean you need  to query all the data and present them in one table? Or actually transfer all the data from table2, table3, table4 to the table1?

Comment: Either i want to create new table or transfer all data from table1, table2, table3 , table4 into table1.

Comment: I think my answer below might be helpful..

Comment: i tried your query before post the question but each tables has 50000 rows when merge them returns 50000 rows as well. Where do i do wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just to query all the data from the tables and present them into one set of results you can try the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
UNION
SELECT * FROM table2
UNION
SELECT * FROM table3
UNION
SELECT * FROM table4
```

If you actually want to transfer all the data from table2, table3, table4 to table1 you can try something like the following:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (Col1, Col2...col7)
SELECT * FROM table1
UNION
SELECT * FROM table2
UNION
SELECT * FROM table3
UNION
SELECT * FROM table4
```